# Error from debugger failed to launch simulator error 4294956467

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am getting this error when I try to run the application on simulator. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I had another user on the same machine running the iOS simulator. Logging in as the other user and quitting the simulator (and Xcode) solved it in my case.